# VBA Access 2007 dependent autoincrement

Tags: vba, reference, ms-access-2007

I'm a little new at this so bear with me. :)

I'm trying to add an event to one of my forms in an Access 2007 database.
The idea is that by entering a value in the CustomerNumber field, the OrderNumber field will automatically figure out the next order number for that customer. (If that customer has two previous orders, then OrderNumber will be a 3)

For example, suppose we have the table:

```
Orders
CustomerNumber    OrderNumber    Description
1                  1              Whatever
1                  2              Blah
2                  1              Yada
5                  1              Yada
2                  2              Yada
1                  3              Foo
```

In this case, if we type CustomerNumber =1 then the OrderNumber will see that there are three previous orders for that customer, and therefore OrderNumber =4.

Similarly, if CustomerNumber = 2, then the OrderNumber = 3.

I've got the following code, but I'm having issues with setting up a reference to the Orders table (variable y) so that it can count the number of orders for that customer.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub CustomerNumber_AfterUpdate()
Dim CustNo As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Object
CustNo = CustomerNumber.Value
y = Nz(DLookup("CustomerNumber", "Orders"), "")
x = DCount("OrderNumber", "Orders", CustNo = y)
OrderNumber = x + 1
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Cabral

Comment: Will more than one person ever use the application at the same time?

Comment: @Hansup: Yes, it could potentially be used by multiple people at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are attempting to count it the way you are but if your only goal is to get the order count for a given customer number what you need is

```
DCount("OrderNumber", "Orders", "CustomerNumber = " & myCustNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I think I was headed off in the wrong direction when I made that initial post. It was easy enough to do in sql so I created a vba code to run the sql version.
Thanks,
Cabral

```
Private Sub CustomerNumber_AfterUpdate()
Dim CustNo As Integer
Dim sqlQuery As Object
CustNo = CustomerNumber.Value
Set sqlQuery = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Orders.CustomerNumber)as Count FROM Orders WHERE CustomerNumber = " & CustNo & ";")
OrderNumber = sqlQuery.Count + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: That's okay, because the different users would have different customer numbers. The order numbers are not unique but the combination of customer and order numbers will be.